# Colors and shapes with several y-variables in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a plot with two y-variables with different shape and color, but I keep failing.

Any suggestions as to where I go wrong?

```
library (ggplot2)
library (forcats)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=drat, group=as_factor(vs)))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=as_factor(vs), color=as_factor(vs))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "yellow")) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cyl))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=drat, shape=as_factor(vs)))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "yellow")) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cyl))
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to change? The only problem I see, is that the colors probably do not work. You use aes(color = vs) but tell ggplot which colors to use for the scale_fill. So either you change it to scale_color_manual or to aes(fill = vs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful to use as.factor (not as_factor), and watch out for typos. Here is the corrected code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y=drat, group=as.factor(vs)))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=as.factor(vs), color=as.factor(vs))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", "yellow")) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(cyl))
```

[image: Plot Output]